# Iterate through nested JSON arrays iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, cocoa

I have a json feed like this:

```
 {
result = {
  cars =  {
        brand = {
             fields = {
       name = {
        id = 1234;
                        value = "Opel Astra";
           };
     description = {
        id = 4432;
        value = "Some description"; 
    };
           };
      fields = {
       name = {
        id = 1453;
                        value = "Opel Omega";
           };
     description = {
        id = 4430;
        value = "Some description"; 
    };
    ...
           };
     };
   };
```

When I parse this, I get all objects in an array and not as a seperate string which is what I want.

I've done like this:

```
NSArray *result = [[res objectForKey:@"result"]valueForKeyPath:@"cars.brand.fields.name.value"];
NSLog(@"%@" , [result objectAtIndex:0]):
```

The output is:

```
(
    "Opel Astra",
    "Opel Omega",
    ....
),
```

How can I achieve getting one string at a time, instead of an array containing a lot of string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [SBJSON](http://jasarien.com/?p=428) to parse the JSON in objective-C.

You can get the SBJSON from [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to retrieve the JSON data into a foundation object.

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134910/retrieving-values-from-json-using-objective-c).

Comment: Can't use NSJSONSerialization because that's only available on iOS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

You are also able to Handle the JSON String as id-Value.
Then you call [jsonString objectForKey:@"result"].

And try this Function, it works perfectly for me ;)

```
- (id) objectInObject:(NSObject *) rootObject forPath:(NSString *) aKeyPath {

NSArray *keys = [aKeyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSObject *anObject = rootObject;


for (NSString *aKey in keys) {
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    bool isArray = NO;

    // check array
    if ([[aKey substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"i:"]) {
        isArray = YES;
        NSArray *values = [aKey componentsSeparatedByString:@":" ];
        arrayIndex = [[values objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    }

    if (isArray) {
        anObject = [(NSArray *) anObject objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
    } else {
        anObject = [(NSDictionary *) anObject objectForKey:aKey];
    }
}
return anObject;
```

}

Comment: Should I just pass an array or a dictionary, for rootObject?

Comment: I tried this method. I passed an NSArray. Still get the same output

Comment: What is the "i:" ? Where do you get that from?

Comment: as Root Object you should pass an id JsonObject. The i: test allows you to set the keyPath "somekey.somearray.i:2", wich will get you the third (because of 0 indexed) Array.

Answer (score 0):

Use SBJson as your JSON lib. Then just use this line of code (response is a string) and you will get expected output you want.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [response JSONValue];
```